# Find the value of the parameter $L$ via Cardano-Vieta's Formula knowing a condition on two roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, roots

*Given $L\in \mathbb{R}$, the equation $f(x)=x^4-Lx^3-2x^2+6x-4=0$ has two roots such that their sum is equal to $-1$. ¿What is the value of $L$?* Here is my attempt. Asumming the four roots are $a,b,c,d$ and $a+b=-1$. The Cardano-Vieta's formulas read as
$$ \begin{cases} abcd = -4 \\ abc +abd+bcd+acd = -6 \\ ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd=-2 \\ a+b+c+d=L\end{cases}$$
Using $a+b=-1$, the last equations arises $c+d=1+L$. So we have 5 equations and 5 incognites. The problem is that I'm stuck in solving this. I could reduce the system to three equations and three variables $(L,d,a)$, but I still  can't solve. **Which is the best way to attack this kind of system?** Maybe Cardano-Vieta's formulas don't fix here very well... Any comment or help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your system brings you back to the $4$th degree equation

Comment: So it seems that Vieta's formula fails here and I need a different approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to solve the system? No way. Remember that an equation with real coefficients for any complex solutions has its conjugate, too.

Comment: That is where I am stuck precisely, in solving that non-linear system. I could reduced it to three variables, but still cant figure it out

Comment: Maybe this is not an appropiate way to solve the problem. The solution, which I found using a computer, is $L=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose one solution is $x_1=a$ the other one is $x_2=-1-a$.

Thus the polynomial $f(x)=x^4-L x^3-2 x^2+6 x-4$ has a factor
$$(x-a)(x+1+a)=x^2+x-a^2-a$$
and another factor $x^2+bx+c$. Thus their product is
$$(x^2+x-a^2-a)(x^2+bx+c)=$$
$$=x^4+(b+1) x^3+x^2 \left(-a^2-a+b+c\right)+x \left(-a^2b-a b+c\right)-a^2 c-a c$$
To be equal to $f(x)$ must be
$$\begin{cases}
b+1=-L\\
-a^2-a+b+c=-2\\
-a^2b-a b+c=6\\
-a^2 c-a c=-4\\
\end{cases}
$$
subtract $3$nd less $2$rd
$$a + a^2 - b - a b - a^2 b=8\to b=\frac{-a^2-a+8}{-a^2-a-1}$$
solve the $4$th wrt $c$
$$c=\frac{4}{a^2+a}$$
and plug these results in the second equation
$$-a^2+\frac{-a^2-a+8}{-a^2-a-1}+\frac{4}{a^2+a}-a=-2\to a=-2;\;a=1$$
substitute $a=1$ to get $b=-2$ and finally substitute in the first equation to have the result $L=1$.

Comment: Thanks Raffaele! Your idea is similar, but the system is much easier! +1